# Why doesn't this Octopus Channel Rule match this package?

Tags: nuget, octopus-deploy

Here are sample version numbers for Nuget packages:

- 1.1.9-version3
- 1.1.8-version3
- 1.1.7-version3

Here are the channel rules for a Channel titled "Version3":

Version Range: [1.1.1-2.0.0]

Tag: version3

I can't make it any simpler - why are these packages not matching the channel rule? Even removing the version range doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Nuget versioning syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/package-versioning), a range is defined by a comma-separator, the hyphen is for defining the pre-release tag.

Your version range should be [1.1.1,2.0.0]. The tag should be correct.